# how to .mkt file in python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

mkt file but not able to open in python.
Please help

i not able to attach file here is some part of content in file when i open with notepad.

"""
 ”^N ÓE    ñ 4    Ae 4 Ø q ’þ  l P ¿ P  1        ”^N †8Œ   "Õ Œ           ò= Œ   Œ   Œ   Œ   x       ÿàõ                 ”^N <&  c   ý%  T  &  MÍ ‹&  <(  Z(  î%  ì'  &  ý%  ý%  &  ç        ”^N R¯  å   ¥  a   ¯  «¬ ö  ê  ê  n  c  ´  ¯  ´  ¯  ×        ”^N €>
   Y=  .  €>  n  >  Ï?  G@  ~;  M?  €>  €>  €>  €>          ”^N ‰Ú      Æ  *   Ú  ³• ox  ht  Ž€  Hq  ]p   €  X  v  Ú  ë       ”^N u
ê  PF    p  ï                      ê      ÿàõ                 ”^N x^¥
    ¥
    & ·é  H ´! ´! » ~% 5 –
 –
 ¥
         ó
”^N 0c   ,   s  ¥      ¢4  ^        °  â              é       ”^N ³;åG     åG
   ïG  h  »G  {H  8J  ´F  IH  åG  åG  åG  åG    "

Comment: hi.. did you figure out a way to open this .mkt file?